# Problema con Summernote: veo las etiquetas del html y no debería ser así

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, express, bootstrap-4

Hola ¿qué tal? Estoy realizando un ejercicio del libro "Beginning Node, Express and MongoDB Development" de Greg Lim. En el  cap. 14 utiliza Summernote en un  dentro de un formulario. Si bien hago lo mismo que muestra el libro (actualizando los link de Summernote) todo pareciera estar bien. Al enviar el contenido del blog se sube mal, el contenido paso a verlo con las etiquetas del html:

Ejemplo:

Lo que se tendría que ver: 
Primero.
Este es el primer día del diario...

Se ve:
<p>Primero.</p>
<p>Este es el <b>primer día</b> del diario...</p>

También aparecen las etiquetas al usar cualquier estilo de la barra de herramientas de Summernote.

*** En el archivo header.ejs:

```
<!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<% if(locals.createPost && createPost) { %>
    <!-- include libraries (jQuery, bootstrap) el script importa la biblioteca, no es el error-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Este script -el error- permite que se integre summernotes con el  cuadro de texto original, al quitarlo veo dos cuadros y no la barra de herramientas, pero el blog se crea como doc html--> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    <!--este script hace que aparezca la barra de herramientas en el cuadro de texto-->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- include summernote css/js -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-bs4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
<% } %>
```

*** En el archivo create.ejs:

```
<div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                        <label>Description</label>
                        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="body" name="body"></textarea>
                        <script>
                            $("#body").summernote({
                                placeholder:'Write here',
                                tabsize: 2,
                                height:200
                            });
                            
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

*** En el archivo newPost.js:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
//Para que un usuario no cree un post sin estar logeado -sí o sí- ponemos:
if(req.session.userId){
    return res.render('create',{
        createPost:true //así aplicamos el editor wysiwyg sólo en create.ejs
    })
}
res.redirect('/auth/login')
```

}

*** En el archivo post.ejs:

```
 <article>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx auto">
                <!--quitar esto no cambia nada-->
                <%- blogpost.body %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

¿Alguien sabrá cómo solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias, Juan.